# Difference between GStreamer 0.10 Library Reference Manual and GStreamer 0.10 Core Reference Manual

Tags: gstreamer

I am just going through the [gstreamer documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/).I couldnt understand the difference between the  [GStreamer 0.10 Library Reference Manual](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/) and [GStreamer 0.10 Core Reference Manual](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/).Most of the fuinction calls like gst_X_funtion_name can be interpreted from the GStreamer 0.10 Core Reference Manual by checking the Gst_X documentation.But why GStreamer 0.10 Library Reference Manual is used and where it is used.
Plz elaborate.
Rgds
Softy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core part is for the core library. The library manaual is for extra libraries (e.g. also containing helper for unit tests, element baseclasses). Using the extra libraries is not strictly needed, thus the split.

Use a tool like devhelp to access the documentation. This will help you to find things easily, without a need to remember in which docuemnt is is.